# How can I set the background color on specific areas of a cufflink plot figure?

Tags: python, visualization, data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2QFy.png)

I want specific areas in my plot to be orange color and some in green. Please check the image in the link provided. How do i create this plot in python cufflinks?

df.iplot(hspan=[(0,20),(40,60)]) this is giving me a band in red color by default. How do i change the color?

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far in your question

Comment: Hi, i have not been able to do this color banding at all. I have been able to plot the details that i wanted to plot but i dont know how to create color bands

Comment: Yes, please include that too in the question. Also, what have you tried or researched.

Comment: df.iplot(hspan=[(0,20),(40,60)])

this is giving me a band in red  color by default. How do i change the color?

Comment: the below method works for multiple bands, but how do i add color :

df.iplot(hspan=[(0,20),(40,60)])

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [documentation notebook](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/), you can add color as an extra parameter passed in the form of dictionary. For example:

```
df.iplot(vspan={'x0':'2015-02-15','x1':'2015-03-15','color':'rgba(30,30,30,0.3)','fill':True,'opacity':.4})
```

Comment: yes but the solution that you have given is for a band which is between x0 and x1. What if i have multiple points like, x0 to x1 and x2 to x3?

Comment: have you tried adding more key-value pairs to the dictionary?

Comment: If I use the keyword vspan twice, i get the below error: 

SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

if i use just 1 vspan and try x0,x1,x2,x3 i get syntax error

Comment: no, try to do it in this way `vspan={'x0':'2015-02-15','x1':'2015-03-15','x2': '....', 'x3': '....', ...`

Comment: yes i had tried that too, but it was showing syntax error @Andreas

Comment: just pass a list to vspan:`vspan=[{'x0':'2015-02-15','x1':'2015-03-15','color':'rgba(30,30,30,0.3)','fill':True,'opacity':.4}{'x0'...','x1':..','color':'rgba(30,30,30,0.3)','fill':True,'opacity':.4}]`